# Laravel - How to export two tables with relationships

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I want to export to Excel in Laravel 5.8 using

> "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"

Models:

1. UserReward (user_rewards)
2. User (user)

I have this Code

```
        $points = DB::table("user_rewards")
         ->select("user_rewards.user_id", "users.username","user_rewards.user_id", DB::raw("SUM(user_rewards.points) as no_game"))
        ->join("users","users.id","=","user_rewards.user_id")
         ->groupBy("users.id","users.username","user_rewards.user_id")
         ->orderByRaw('SUM(user_rewards.points) DESC');
```

But wants to converts it to something like this

Exports

```
class GamesExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{  
    use Exportable;
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function query()
    {
        return User::query()->select('name', 'username', 'created_at');
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I export two tables with relationships using

> query()->select

or convert the

> DB::raw above to
>
> query()->select

as shown above

Answer (score 1):

You can try eager loading the relationship using `with`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

That way it would be something like this:
`User::with('userRewards')` (assuming `userRewards` is the name of the relationship)